# Program that chooses a winner of the election

Tags: c++

I've got to make a c++ program in which:
1)first line of input are two numbers; first(n) is the number of candidates(m) and the second in the number of votes in general;
2)second line of input are votes
my task is to count votes and say, who the winner is; i should also display the num of votes every candidate had.
ex:

```
input:
3 10
1 3 2 1 2 2 3 3 2 2 
output:
1: 2
2: 5
3: 3
2
```

I've written a program but it doesn't loop over every oportunity and i have no idea how to improwve it

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int candidates;
    int votes;
    int vote[votes];
    cin >> candidates >> votes;
    int winner = 1;

    //attaching votes to a list
    for (int i = 1; i<=votes; i++) {
        cin >> vote[i];
    }; 

    //loop through candidates
    for (int k = 1; k<=candidates; k++){
        int value = 0;
        //search true the list of votes
        for (int z = 1; z<=votes; z++) {
            if(k == vote[z]) {
                value = value + 1;
            };
            cout << value << "\n";  
            if (value > winner) {
               winner = k;
            };
        };
        //give the result:
        cout << k <<":"<<value<<"\n";
    };
    cout << winner << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Please help c:

also, if the person no. 1 has 3 votes, and the person no.2 has also 3 votes, the winner should be the first candidate. My code doesn't work this way, any hints?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: A few hints though: Uninitialized variables are really uninitialized, their values will be *indeterminate* (and seem random) and using them will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Then don't forget that order matters, using a variable *before* initializing it will not go back and redo the use retroactively. Lastly, C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: also, if the person no. 1 has 3 votes, and the person no.  has also 3 votes, the winner should be the first candidate. My code doesn't work this way, any hints?

Comment: Array indices are zero based in c++. An array of 10 elements has elements as positions 0 to 9 inclusively.

Comment: i know this, but how does it solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In C++,  you can use [vectors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to dynamically allocated serial data (i.i., a "variable length array"). While fixing your code is hard for me, I wrote a possible solution to your problem using vectors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int candidates = 0; // Number of candidates
    int voters = 0;      // Number of voters
    cout<<"Enter the number of candidates and voters\n";
    cin >> candidates >> voters;
    vector<int> result(candidates, 0); // Vector to hold the results

    // Do voting; you can count the votes immediately,
    // so no need of a vector to hold the votes.
    int vote = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < voters; ++i )
    {
        cout<<"Enter vote by voter "<<i+1<<':';
        while( (vote <= 0) || (vote > candidates) )
            cin >> vote; // if the entered votes are invalid, user enters the number again
        ++result[vote-1]; // credit candidate for whom the vote was cast
        vote = 0;         // reset vote
    };

    // Find the winner; there are standard C++ functions for this,
    // but we will do it by hand for now.
    int winner = 0;
    cout<<"\nResults: \n";
    for( int j = 0; j < candidates; ++j )
    {
        if(result[winner] < result[j])
            winner = j; // If someone has more votes, he is the winner
        cout<<"Candidate "<<(j+1)<<": "<<result[j]<<'\n';
    }
    cout<<"The winner is: "<<winner+1<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```